# Relativistic mass of photon in motion

Tags: special-relativity, photons, mass, speed-of-light, mass-energy

There are two expressions regarding relativistic mass of photon; namely relativistic approach:

$$m = \frac {m_0} {({1 - \frac {v^2 } {c^2 }) } ^\frac {1 } {2} }. $$

And, energy-mass equivalence formula:

$$ E =  m {c}^2. $$

> There common uses in physics books:

First formula is used to prove that rest mass of photon is zero.

Second formula is used to find out what is called kinetic mass of photon in motion.

> MY QUESTION:
>   first formula suggests that photon must have infinite mass in motion, and second gives finite mass (kinetic), why is this disperacy?

Comment: Zero divided by zero is not infinity.

Comment: The complete equation is $E^2=(pc)^2+(mc^2)^2$.
Photons are massless, so their energy is equal to their momentum. $E=pc$.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3541/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/297774/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Well, by definition a photon (a uniparticle state of the quantized e-m field) is massless, i.e. has mass = 0. There is no photon at rest, so that "photon in motion" is a linguistic mistake called pleonasm.

The first formula you wrote is applicable to objects with non-zero mass (inertial mass, or rest mass - you can see that for photons these two terms do not apply, there's no rest state/IRF at rest for a photon and inertia as opposition to acceleration doesn't apply, as photons are not subject to acceleration/deceleration), so it is pointless to invoke it here.

Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass#Definitions_of_mass or some wonderful articles by the late Lev Okun, such as this one: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0602037

Answer (score 1):

None of the formulae you quote can be used to conclude that the mass of a photon is zero. The formula that should be used to do so is the generic special relativistic relation $E^2 - p^2c^2 = m^2c^4 $ in conjunction with the formula relating the energy and momentum of a photon $E=pc$. Putting this latter formula into the former immediately yields $m=0$, i.e. that mass of a photon is zero.

Comment: To be clear,  the  symbol $m$ in your answer denotes the *invariant mass* while the symbol $m$ in the OP's question does  not.  This might lead to some confusion.